# Python email MIME attachment filename

Tags: python-2.7, csv, mime, email-attachments

I'm having trouble attaching a CSV file to an email. I can send the email fine using smtplib, and I can attach my CSV file to the email. But I cannot set the name of the attached file, and so I cannot set it to be `.csv`. Also I can't figure out how to add a text message to the body of the email.

This code results in an attachment called <kbd>AfileName.dat</kbd>, not the desired <kbd>testname.csv</kbd>, or better still <kbd>attach.csv</kbd>

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email import Encoders
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase

def main():
    print"Test run started"
    sendattach("Test Email","attach.csv", "testname.csv")
    print "Test run finished"

def sendattach(Subject,AttachFile, AFileName):
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = Subject 
    msg['From'] = "from@email.com"
    msg['To'] =  "to@email.com"
    #msg['Text'] = "Here is the latest data"

    part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
    part.set_payload(open(AttachFile, "rb").read())
    Encoders.encode_base64(part)

    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=AFileName')

    msg.attach(part)

    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.com",XXX)
    server.login("from@email.com","password")
    server.sendmail("email@email.com", "anotheremail@email.com", msg.as_string())

if __name__=="__main__":
main()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the line `part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=AFileName')` you are hardcoding `AFileName` as part of the string and are not using the the same named function's argument.

To use the argument as the filename change it to

```
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=AFileName)
```

To add a body to your email

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
msg.attach(MIMEText('here goes your body text', 'plain'))
```

Comment: And my supplementary question was - how do I add some text to the body of the email ? I tried msg['Text'] = "Here is the latest data", but nothing happened

Comment: For me extension was causing an issue. The attachment was sending as `attachment1`. So I changed into `filename = name + '.pdf'`