# Sending email with multiple attachments using smpt

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtp, smtplib

I have this script that sends emails with multiple attachments to multiple users. However, the attachments' file names are set as their path.

Received files

[image]

Terminal Output

[image]

How can I set their names as the actual file names, thanks.

"""

```
import os 
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEImage import MIMEImage
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email import Encoders


#Set up crap for the attachments
files = "/tmp/test/dbfiles"
filenames = [os.path.join(files, f) for f in os.listdir(files)]
#print filenames


#Set up users for email
gmail_user = "joe@email.com"
gmail_pwd = "somepasswd"
recipients = ['recipient1','recipient2']

#Create Module
def mail(to, subject, text, attach):
   msg = MIMEMultipart()
   msg['From'] = gmail_user
   msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)
   msg['Subject'] = subject

   msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

   #get all the attachments
   for file in filenames:
      part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
      part.set_payload(open(file, 'rb').read())
      Encoders.encode_base64(part)
      part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % file)
      msg.attach(part)

   mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
   mailServer.ehlo()
   mailServer.starttls()
   mailServer.ehlo()
   mailServer.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
   mailServer.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg.as_string())
   # Should be mailServer.quit(), but that crashes...
   mailServer.close()

#send it
mail(recipients,
   "Todays report",
   "Test email",
   filenames)
```

"""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there might be a solution in this link:

[Python email MIME attachment filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29239572/python-email-mime-attachment-filename)

Basically what the solution is according to that post is change your this line:

```
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % file)
```

to this line :

```
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=AFileName)
```

Which comes down to this final change:

```
  #get all the attachments
  for file in filenames:
  
  part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
  part.set_payload(open(file, 'rb').read())
  Encoders.encode_base64(part)
  
  ***part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=file)***

  msg.attach(part)
```

[Documentation on how to use add_header](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.add_header)

Hope that helps! :D

## Update

Having this in your for loop should give you the filenames:

```
for file in filenames:

    actual_filenames = os.path.basename(file)

    #Your code

    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=actual_filenames)
```

Comment: Still got the same result, not sure what went wrong there.

Comment: In your for loop, " for file in filenames:" can you do a print(file) to show us the output of that @SaadAbdulla

Comment: Please add requested image in your comments or your original post
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JED2E.png
@SaadAbdulla

Comment: Sure, I added it to my post.

Comment: @SaadAbdulla I have edited my answer, please take a look at the changes made and let me know if it helps.

Comment: That did the job, really appreciate the help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if it is in the same directory:

```
import os                                  
for f in os.listdir('.'):                                                                                               
    fn, fext = os.path.splitext(f)
```

Comment: Didn't understand the second line, are you sure about the syntix? Where will it fit exactly in the script?

Comment: f = file name: so if you put your script inside a for loop and send "f" its going to send all the files in the directory